# UserId Not correct

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-groups

So I'm guessing this is just a basic error but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I'm trying to create a new user, set some attributes and add them to a group I've already made. The following code all works but for the line:
`craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($newUser->getContent()->id, 11);`

```
public function actionSendSignup()
{
   $this->requirePostRequest();

   $user = new UserModel();
   $user->username  = craft()->request->getPost('memberEmail');
   $user->unverifiedEmail  = craft()->request->getPost('memberEmail');

   $data = [
       "firstName" => craft()->request->getPost('memberFirstName'),
       "lastName" => craft()->request->getPost('memberLastName'),
       "email" => craft()->request->getPost('memberEmail'),
   ];

   $user->setAttributes($data);
   $user->pending = true;

   $success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

   if ($success) {
       craft()->search->indexElementAttributes($user);


       // Assign them to my user group 11
       craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($newUser->getContent()->id, 11);

       // Update the Element Index
       craft()->search->indexElementAttributes($user);
   }

   return $this->returnJson($user->getContent());

}
```

The get id returns a number that appears right (it's a low integer), but I get a SQL error on adding the row to the join table users_usergroups and the userId doesn't match the user that was created in the system.

I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding the user id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$newUser->getContent()->id` will return the primary key from the `craft_content` table, not from the `craft_users` table.

You'll want to use `$newUser->id`, instead.

Comment: awesome, yeah that makes perfect sense now - knew it was something simple.